# Symfony console component, class not found

Tags: php, symfony, class

I'm using the console component without Symfony standard edition and I'm working on my application.php file. When I run it it says:

> Fatal error: Class 'GenerateTableCommand' not found in D:\ConnectCommand\vendor\application.php on line 10

My code:

```
    <?php

require __DIR__.'\autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

    $application = new Application();

    $application->add(new GenerateTableCommand());

    $application->run();

?>
```

My repository can be found here if needed: https://github.com/guuse/ConnectCommand

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there's no `\GenerateTableCommand`, as stated in the error message.

This class is under `AppBundle\Command` namespace, so it's full name is `AppBundle\Command\GenerateTableCommand`.

You should add `use` statement at the beggining:

```
use AppBundle\Command\GenerateTableCommand;
```

Anyway, you'll probably encounter further issues with loading this class, since you do not really have any autoloaders for your custom code, so PHP won't be able to load this class.

Also mixing 3rd party code with your own (in `vendor` directory) is not a good idea.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my answer, you also don't have an autoloader for your code.

Comment: I'm quite new to symfony and the console component, do you have any idea how I could make my command work? I've followed the guide on their website but I still get the same error

Comment: That's because you're not using Symfony Standard Edition, but only the Symfony Framework which is actually a set of components. If you're just starting with Symfony (or even with PHP since it seems you're not aware of autoloaders) maybe it would be better to try with Symfony Standard. Anyway your issue is not related to Symfony but PHP itself. You need an autoloader for you custom code. The easiest way for you is to use Composer to generate it for you. Take a look here for more info: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: I added this to my composer.json and updated the autoload file but it still doesnt seem to work: "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"AppBundle\\": "AppBundle/Command/GenerateTableCommand.php"}
    }
}

Comment: It would be something like: `{ "psr-4": {"AppBundle\\": "AppBundle/"} } }`

Comment: Im still getting the same errors :( could u please check my github repo and see what i'm doing wrong. I feel really stupid. https://github.com/guuse/ConnectCommand

Comment: Your composer.json didn't change. So you didn't add this autoloader definition.